# Javascript works in jsfiddle but not in ASP .net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I want to filter list of items by clicking on one column/string in list item. When I click on Sales, only items in list from Sales category will be displayed. When I click again on Sales all items in list will be displayed.

It works like I want on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pMsR/1/)

But why it is not working in Visual Studio on ASP .net ? It throws exception in

```
...
var a = p.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
...
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true" id="testList">
            <li data-icon="false">
                <p class="ui-li-heading"> 
                  <strong> 1</strong>
                </p>

                <p class="ui-li-aside"> 
                    <span>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="areaItem" id="areaItem">Sales</a>
                        &nbsp;
                        &nbsp;
                    </span>
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check" style="display: inline-block;"></span>    
                </p>
            </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
var filtered = 0;

$(".areaItem").click(function () {
    var SearchTerm = $(this).text();

    var ul = document.getElementById("testList");
    var liArray = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for(var i=0; i<liArray.length; i++) {
        var p = liArray[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        var a = p.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        if(filtered == 1) {
            $(liArray[i]).show();
        } else {
            if(a.text.localeCompare(SearchTerm) != 0) {
                $(liArray[i]).hide();
            }
        }
    }

    if (filtered == 0) {
        filtered = 1;
    } else {
        filtered = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you debug to check the `p` element exists ?

Comment: Are you sure that there are `a` elements in `p`? if not, the Error is thrown because you're effectively trying to assign `a = undefined[0];` <-- getting the zero'th element from undefined isn't quite possible AFAIK

Comment: It works correctly in jsfiddle. In visual studio, p element has in innerHTML field exactly the stuff I want.

Comment: I think you need to wrap your jQuery code "$(function() { $(".areaItem")... });" in order to ensure the "areaItem" element is available in the DOM.

Comment: @rontornambe didn't really help

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem is there some other way to get access to information in <a> tag ??

Comment: You're clearly using jQuery, why not use jQuery to it's full extent? `$('#testList > li').each(function(){ console.log($(this).find('p > a'));});` or something

Comment: what did mean it do not work in visual studio? are you trying to debug the code in VS? Visual studio should not run any javascript code at all. are you using IE test your site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to start by refactoring your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //Make sure doc is loaded
   var list = $("#testList");
   var listItems = $(list).find("li"); //could also do $("#listtest li);

   $(".areaItem").click(function () {
       var parentLi = $(this).closest("li");   //Get li that encloses clicked item 
       $(listItems).not(parentLi).toggle();    //Toggle display of other li
   });
});
```

It is a lot simpler and more inline with how jQuery is meant to be used.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5pMsR/3/

That in itself my not be enough to fix your problem. Double check what is rendered to the page. Particularly check  `id`'s as ASP.net is notorious for mangling IDs. Google ASP.net name mangling and asp.net ID mangling for more info. If your IDs are mangled use the following in your script

```
var list = $('#<%= YourListElement.ClientID%>');
```

or use a class.

**UPDATE**

Upon re-reading your question I've realized that my solution may not meet your needs. If you want both "Sales" items visible if either of them are clicked you could use the following:

```
var list = $("#testList");
var listItems = $(list).find("li"); //could also do $("#listtest li);

$(".areaItem").click(function () {
    var parentLi = $(this).closest("li");  //Get Parent li of clicked element
    var filter = $(parentLi).find(".areaItem").text(); //Set Filter based on text of clicked item
    $(listItems).filter(function(){ //Use jQuery filter to find based on text
        //in the filter context 'this' is a li being filtered not the item clicked
        //$(this).find(".areaItem").text() is used to compare against all list items text
        return $(this).find(".areaItem").text() != filter;
    }).toggle();

});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5pMsR/8/

**Update 2**

I've updated the code and fiddle above to make the solution more robust based on comments. It would appear that the `a` tag is not present in the final render. The code changes will now search based on CSS class as opposed to tag.

Comment: I tried your solution which looks definitely better but it was not working in .net, when I click on any 'areaItem' , all li disappear.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with some debug alerts in it:http://jsfiddle.net/5pMsR/6/. That might help you work out what is going wrong. Check the HTML as rendered to the page in a browser (view source, or use firebug for firefox). Is there an `a` tag in the list item? If not this would also cause your initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem like this in the past: the issue was with the ASP.NET page life cycle and the javascript being parsed before the element(s) was created in the DOM. Since you are attempting to bind a click handler to the `.areaItem` class, the elements that are members of that class must all be available in the DOM when the function gets parsed.

From memory I think I ended up delegating the click to the document thusly:

```
$(document).on(click, ".areaItem", function() { <function content> });
```

I believe this makes the parsing occur after the `load` event, at which time all elements have been created.

The reason I am not sure is because I deleted all of this code out and did it a different way: by putting the script block directly in my content page after the ASP controls and HTML. Not ideal if you were wanting to have the JS in the header or a separate file, but embedding it after the content does appear to work:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true" id="testList">
        <li data-icon="false">
            <p class="ui-li-heading"> 
              <strong> 1</strong>
            </p>

            <p class="ui-li-aside"> 
                <span>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="areaItem" id="areaItem">Sales</a>
                    &nbsp;
                    &nbsp;
                </span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check" style="display: inline-block;"></span>    
            </p>
        </li>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var filtered = 0;

  $(".areaItem").click(function () {
    var SearchTerm = $(this).text();

    var ul = document.getElementById("testList");
    var liArray = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for(var i=0; i<liArray.length; i++) {
        var p = liArray[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        var a = p.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        if(filtered == 1) {
            $(liArray[i]).show();
        } else {
            if(a.text.localeCompare(SearchTerm) != 0) {
                $(liArray[i]).hide();
            }
        }
    }

    if (filtered == 0) {
        filtered = 1;
    } else {
        filtered = 0;
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came with solution which is little bit miracle to me, since I am new to javascript.
All is working fine in IE but in Chrome all li disappear after click.

```
var filtered = 0;

        $(".areaItem").click(function () {
            var SearchTerm = $(this).text();

            $('#testList > li').each(function () {
                var a = $(this).find("a").attr("id","areaItem");

                //alert(a[0].innerHTML);

                if (filtered == 1) {
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    //alert(a.text());
                    if (a[0].innerHTML.localeCompare(SearchTerm) != 0) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }

            });


            if (filtered == 0) {
                filtered = 1;
            } else {
                filtered = 0;
            }
        });
```